# fopen() uploading file permissions affected by adding group permissions to directory

Tags: php, linux, upload, permissions, file-permissions

I'm making a social media site.
I have a set of pre-defined image locations inc.

1. images/backgrounds/
2. images/users/

With sub-directorys inc.

1. thumb/
2. small/
3. medium/
4. large/

Each of the folders to this point have following permissions:

[image: File Permissions on directories]

chrismoore being the creator and TrybeDev being the users who have ability to access the files.

A bit more contact.. I want to allow any of the websites users to be able to upload images to these directories. But at the moment i'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: fopen(directory/x_images/x_trybes/current/thumb/dee319ff0b723dc7b5c481d07bd85210e255a36f.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /directory/functions.php on line 1056
```

This error has occurred when I added the group to each of the directories. I'm sick of changing these permissions. So is there any solution to allow any website users to write to the thumb/ small/ directories without causing this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What linux distribution do you have?

Comment: The distribution is Debian 7.5

Comment: And do you have selinux enabled or not?

Comment: I havn't enabled it. So it's probably disabled.

Comment: Run me please a `sestatus` command, and check it to make you sure.

Comment: Linux 3.15.4-x86_64-linode45 #1 SMP Mon Jul 7 08:42:36 EDT 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux thats what I got from running uname -a.

Comment: No command found for `sestatus`

Comment: MM. try to mcedit /var/log/apache2/error.log and check the file read error lines.

Comment: Permission denied. I'm not the best at server config.

Comment: U have to be root when doing this.

Comment: I am a sudo root user

Comment: Try to set all of dir's owner as `www-data` for testing, after that you can set back to original owners. After u set try to upload file.

Comment: Just the directories mentioned above?

Comment: @TamásSzabó it works when I change the root user back to www-data

Comment: Is `www-data` added to the good group?

Comment: @TamásSzabó I changed the owner from me - "chrismoore" to www-data. Are you saying I should add www-data to the group?

Comment: Yes, you should create a group for users, and put in the www-data, to be able to access bot user, and apache too.

Comment: @TamásSzabó What about just making www-data the owner of the directories of what contents will be changed?

Comment: Thats also good, but never forgot to do this, when adding new folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check `/etc/selinux/config` if selinux is enforced.

If it is enforce,change to

```
SELINUX=disable
```

Don't forget to restart apache